# What's the best practice to infer the methods?

Tags: casting, go

I have a custom time format which I use to properly encode/decode json. However whenever I need to do a time computation I need to do a cast. Is this the right way? It feels a bit ugly to keep casting. For example when I need to "update" the value I need to cast it twice ( once to time and once to my type)

```
type Mytime time.Time
var t Mytime
t = Mytime(time.Now())
// Add an hour to my typed time
t = Mytime(time.Time(t).Add(1 * time.Hour))
```

Comment: Puzzled what 'var t Mytime(time.Now())' means at all. Seems like it's syntactically illegal. Does it's a shortcut for 'var t Mytime=Mytime(time.Now())'?

Comment: @Uvelichitel It's invalid. I assumed it was a typo of `var t = Mytime(…)`

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you have `type Mytime time.Time`. If instead you embedded it:

```
type MyTime struct {
        time.Time
}
```

Then you could have:

```
func (t MyTime) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
        … whatever …
}
```

and still access all of `time.Time`'s methods.
E.g. something like:

```
        t := MyType{time.Now()}
        t.Time = t.Add(time.Hour)
```

---

Fuller example showing differences between embedded and non-embedded custom time types. Note that embedding still doesn't allow for transparent inter-use with things that expect a `time.Time` value. (The reason for making these types, e.g. to add a `MarshalJSON` method has been omitted here).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type YourTime time.Time

type MyTime struct{ time.Time }

// Some random functions, perhaps in a third party package,
// that deals with time.Time values.
func fn(t time.Time) {
    fmt.Println("fn got:", t)
}

func fn2() time.Time {
    return time.Unix(14e8, 0)
}

func main() {
    var t1 = YourTime(time.Now())
    //t1 = t1.Add(time.Hour)             // compiler error
    t1 = YourTime(time.Time(t1).Add(time.Hour))
    fmt.Println("ugly t1:", t1)
    fmt.Println("nice t1:", time.Time(t1))
    //fn(t1)                        // compiler error
    fn(time.Time(t1))

    //t1 = fn2()                    // compiler error
    t1 = YourTime(fn2())

    var t2 = MyTime{time.Now()}
    // t2 = t2.Add(time.Hour)       // compiler error
    t2.Time = t2.Add(time.Hour)
    fmt.Println("t2:", t2)
    //fn(t2)                        // compiler error
    fn(t2.Time)

    //t2 = fn2()                    // compiler error
    t2.Time = fn2()
}
```

[<kbd>Playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/Of0NDTtokK)

Output:

```
ugly t1: {63393494400 0 0x1c9340}
nice t1: 2009-11-11 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
fn got: 2009-11-11 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
t2: 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
fn got: 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

Comment: time.Add() return time.Time, not MyTime.

Comment: @Uvelichitel, okay, I changed it to show assignment of Add result.

Comment: So a cast is still required back to `MyTime`

Comment: @pero yes, but it's not a cast. For some `var tt time.Time` it's either `newval := MyTime{tt}` or `oldval.Time = tt`.