# How to override inbuilt type

Tags: struct, go, interface

By default `time.Duration` prints it in the format `2h0m0s` etc.

However, I want to print it as `2 Hours` or `2 Hours 1 Min`

One way, I can do that is to create a new `struct TimeDurationStruct` and create a `String()` function. I have done the same in [golang playground](http://play.golang.org/p/mB2JvfjoZe)

#### Working Code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "math"
)

type TimeDurationStruct struct {
    t time.Duration
}

func (i *TimeDurationStruct) Set(t time.Duration) {
    i.t = t
}

func (i TimeDurationStruct) String() string {
    duration := i.t

    var dayString, hourMinString string
    var days, hours float64

    totalHours := duration.Hours()
    minutes := math.Mod(duration.Minutes(), 60.0)
    if totalHours < 24.0 {
        hours = totalHours
    } else {
        hours = math.Mod(totalHours, 24.0)
        days = totalHours / 24.0
    }

    if hours == 0 {

    } else if hours < 1 {
        if minutes == 1 {
            hourMinString = "1 Min"
        } else {
            hourMinString = fmt.Sprintf("%g Mins", minutes)
        }
    } else if hours >= 1 && hours < 2 {
        if minutes == 0 {
            hourMinString = "1 Hour"
        } else if minutes == 1 {
            hourMinString = "1 Hour 1 Min"
        } else {
            hourMinString = fmt.Sprintf("1 Hour %g Mins", minutes)
        }
    } else {
        if minutes == 0 {
            hourMinString = fmt.Sprintf("%g Hours", hours)
        } else if minutes == 1 {
            hourMinString = fmt.Sprintf("%g Hours 1 Min", hours)
        } else {
            hourMinString = fmt.Sprintf("%g Hours %g Mins", hours, minutes)
        }
    }

    if days > 0 {
        if days == 1 {
            dayString = "1 Day"
        } else {
            dayString = fmt.Sprintf("%g Days ", days)
        }
    }

    return dayString + hourMinString
}

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    d := t.Add(2 * time.Hour).Sub(t)
    fmt.Println(d)
    var i TimeDurationStruct
    i.Set(d)
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

#### Questions

1. Instead of a structure type, is it possible to override `time.Duration` `type`. E.g

   ```
   type TimeDurationStruct time.Duration
   ```

   I tried it [here](http://play.golang.org/p/2AKd2bTQvA), but it does not work...
2. Is there a better/easier way ?

Comment: There is [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29397985/55504) to another question that shows the differences between embedding (which by the way is what you probably should have done here instead of a non-exported named field) and non-embedding a custom `time.Time` type.

Comment: I updated the question, as to whether I can override time.Duration type's String() function only. Awesome, I now used embedded type and that works http://play.golang.org/p/tWyd48ajpl

Answer (score 0):

Following on from your question edit, yes you can achieve this effect without a struct.  The problem is that when you define your type with:

```
type TimeDurationStruct time.Duration
```

your new `TimeDurationStruct` type will not inherit any of the methods from `time.Duration` like you had when you used the type embedding option.  You can still access those methods, but you will need to perform a type cast.  So the start of your `String` method should be modified to read something like:

```
func (i TimeDurationStruct) String() string {
    duration := time.Duration(i)
    ...
```