# Calling method of named type

Tags: inheritance, methods, go

I have a named type, which I needed to make to do some JSON unmarshmaling:

```
type StartTime time.Time
func (st *StartTime) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {...}
```

Since `StartTime` is a `time.Time`, I thought that I would be able to call methods that belong to `time.Time`, such as `Date()`:

```
myStartTime.Date() // myStartTime.Date undefined (type my_package.StartTime has no field or method Date)
```

How can I add methods to an existing type, while preserving its original methods?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397801/whats-the-best-practice-to-infer-the-methods/29397985#29397985) for examples on the difference between embedding/not-embedding a custom time type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `type` keyword you are creating a new type and as such it will not have the methods of the underlying type.

Use embedding:

```
type StartTime struct {
    time.Time
}
```

Quoting from the [Spec: Struct types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types):

> A field or [method](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations) `f` of an anonymous field in a struct `x` is called *promoted* if `x.f` is a legal selector that denotes that field or method `f`.

So all the methods and fields of the embedded (anonymous) fields are promoted and can be referred to.

Example using it:

```
type StartTime struct {
    time.Time
}

func main() {
    s := StartTime{time.Now()}
    fmt.Println(s.Date())
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/srY1ZAloNI)):

```
2009 November 10
```

Comment: Did not know about the `promotion` functionality, thanks!

Comment: @Tyler Thanks for the edit. Also edited the code on the Playground and posted the new link.